# Image text on same line

Tags: html, css, image

I've been trying for a long time to display an image alongside text. I want to display the resources/rupee.png image in the same line as the cost but the cost appears on the bottom of the image.
Here's my php code:

```
...
    $display_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eportal");

                        echo "<table id='pageTable'><thead><tr><th>Item code</th><th>Image</th><th>Description</th><th>Cost</th></tr></thead>";
                        echo "<tbody>";
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
                            echo "<tr><td>".$row['itemid']."</td><td>";
                            echo '<img src="resources/wh/'.$row['itemid'].'.png" title="'.$row['itemid'].'"/>';
                            echo "</td><td>".$row['description']."</td><td><span>";
                            echo '<img src="resources/rupee.png" />';
                            echo '</span><span class="cost">'.$row['cost'].'</span></td></tr>';
                        }
                        echo "</tbody>";
                        echo "</table>";
...
```

and the relevant CSS: (I may have messed up my CSS code trying to do this for a long time)

```
#pageTable span{
    float:left
}
#pageTable .cost{
    float:left;
}
#pageTable span img{
    padding:3px 0 0 0;
    display : inline !important;
}
```

Comment: CSS works with HTML, your php is entirely irrelevant to the question; please post the relevant HTML that is sent to the browser ('view source').

Comment: ..<td><span><img src="resources/rupee.png" /></span><span class="cost">500</span></td>...

Comment: I did it by adjusting the margin property. But I needed a more optimized way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this may not directly answer your specific query, I would argue that you shouldn't be trying to accomplish the task in this way (if you're still looking to use the 'img' element as in your current markup, some of the other suggested solutions should work fine).

If I was creating this application I'd either use the relevant Unicode symbols to express currencies (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign), or I'd just use text ("Indian Rupees" or whatever). If you *do* want to use a special image symbol, I would tend to discourage you from using 'img' before every amount of money as this will create a lot of repetition and in my opinion isn't very clean. A nice solution might be to use some CSS pseudo-elements on some custom classes:

**HTML:**

```
​<span class="currency rupee">500</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.currency:before {
    vertical-align:-2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.rupee:before {
    content: url(resources/rupee.png); /* Little 16x16 currency symbol */
}
```

​

Comment: The Unicode symbol for "Rupee" don't work in every browser. That was the first thing I'd tried. For all the special symbols I always use Unicode symbols.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the Rupee symbol is Unicode 6.0+. The other alternatives I've specified in my post should work as fine alternatives though (as will an icon font if this is the path you want to go down).

Comment: Yeah. Though, thanks for the "before" tip. I'd completely forgotten about this one.

Comment: @user1445759 Don't forget to mark whichever answer that you found answered your question as correct.

Comment: I just changed the margin property by adding a class and attaching it to the symbol's-image. It worked. It might not be the best way but I just needed it for a small site.
However, for your sake I've marked your question as a "helpful answer". I hope you do not downvote the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just simply align them like this? I don't think you need some fancy CSS for it unless your layout requires it.

```
<img src="resources/rupee.png" style="vertical-align: middle"> COST_TEXT_HERE
```

Comment: I found a way. Changed the margin property.

Answer (score 3):

use align on image tag

```
<img src="" align="texttop" />
```

Comment: In CSS: style="vertical-align:text-top". Best solution I found for this problem. Depending on the height of the image, "text-bottom" might be better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just want to use a currency symbol as an image in text. Use a simpler approach then:

```
<img src="resources/rupee.png" alt="Rs " style="height: 1em" />42.00
```

(replace 42.00 by whatever code you use to insert an actual number).

Depending on the design of the image, you may need to tune its vertical position using CSS (`vertical-align` or, better, relative positioning), so that the symbol appears to sit on the baseline of text. To get help with such tuning, post the URL of the image.

Comment: Thanks. But I changed the margin property of my cost.

Answer (score 0):

you could of course just have the image and text in seperate tds...

like: (left out all attributes etc)

```
<tr>
    <td><img /></td>
    <td><span></span></td>
    <td><img /></td>
    <td><span></span></td>
    <td><img /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    img{
        display : inline !important; 
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="img.png"><span class="cost">cost</span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: joesavage, You are tight, display:block is not necessary. I removed it.